# Why is ZZ not saving in VsVim 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, vsvim

I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 and installed VsVim. Every command I normally use works except `ZZ`. I expect it to save and close the currently opened file. However, its current behavior is to close the opened file without saving.

Comment: This is also happening for me with `:wq<Enter>`.